# Modal Bottom Sheet shows navigation bar in full screen activities

Tags: android, android-layout, bottom-sheet

I have implemented a Modal Bottom Sheet Fragment in a FullScreen Activity. The problem is that when I show the fragment, the navigation bar appears. Here is my code for showing the fragment:

```
OptionsFragment optionsFragment=OptionsFragment.newInstance();
optionsFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(),"options_fragment");
```

And this is the fragment:

```
public class OptionsFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {


    public OptionsFragment() {
    }

    public static OptionsFragment newInstance() {
        OptionsFragment fragment = new OptionsFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.options_layout,container,false);
        return view;
    }

}
```

And finally, this is how I hide the toolbar and the navigation bar at the beginning of the activity:

```
mContentView.setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
```

Answer (score 3):

Since the BottomSheetFragment creates dialog, It is rendered in a window different from the activity's window. So, you'll have to apply these systemUiVisibility flags to the dialog window too.

```
    public class OptionsFragment extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

            //other overridden methods

            @Override
            public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState); 

         dialog.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LOW_PROFILE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                        | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION);
                    return dialog;
                }
    }
```

Even in activity, set systemUiVisibility flags to window decorview instead of contentview

Comment: Unfortunately, it does the same. If I won't succed in finding a solution, I think I'll use a BottomSheetBehaviour instead.

Comment: Make sure you are calling getDecoreView() on window from dialog.